# Shorten equal checks

Tags: java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {
    private String id;
    private String section;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String username;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UpdateAccount {
    private String section;
    private String name;
}
```

I have 2 classes called `UpdateAccount` and `Account` and in my App class, I want to find out if there is any difference between the Account object and the UpdateAccount object. Here is my App class code.
Is there any other ways to code the if-else equal part?

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Account account = new Account("123", "sectionA", "p1", "test", "TestUser1");
        UpdateAccount updateAccount = new UpdateAccount("sectionA", "p11");

        Set<String> diff = new HashSet<>();
        if(!updateAccount.getName().equals(account.getName())){
            diff.add("name");
        }
        if(!updateAccount.getSection().equals(account.getSection())){
            diff.add("section");
        }
        System.out.println(diff);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could get the fields and compare values using reflection, but for just 2 fields, i doubt it's worth it.

Comment: It could be done using reflection, but that's almost always bad advice. Another more useful way would be a functional approach. But if this is just about those 2 fields, any other way than what you already do would result in more code and certainly more complexity of your code.

Comment: If you want to use the "equals check" multiple times, defining a method for it, for example a isAccount method on UpdateAccount, that does the same checks as you, but internally, may be a good idea, or do you just want to know other ways like reflection? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the logic into a common method like this:

```
private static <T> void checkDifference(Set<String> diff, String name, T v1, T v2) {
  if (!Objects.equals(v1, v2)) {
    diff.add(name);
  }
}
```

And then change your main method to look like this:

```
Set<String> diff = new HashSet<>();
checkDifference(diff, "name", updateAccount.getName(), account.getName());
checkDifference(diff, "section", updateAccount.getSection(), account.getSection());
System.out.println(diff);
```

You can further abstract this away by storing the combination of name, a `Function<UpdateAccount, T>` and a `Function<Account, T>` and looping over them, but it's not clear that this would actually help.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reflection, use `Function`s to retrieve the values from the class:

```
  //this stores method references to the getters 
  //as well as the fieldname string that you
  // want to output in your Set
  @AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
  private static class DiffField {
    String fieldname;
    Function<Account, String> accountGetter;
    Function<UpdateAccount, String> updateAccountGetter;
  }

  public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Account account = new Account("123", "sectionA", "p1", "test", "TestUser1");
      UpdateAccount updateAccount = new UpdateAccount("sectionA", "p11");

      //create a list of things to compare, specifying the getter references
      List<DiffField> diffFieldList = List.of(
          DiffField.of("name", Account::getName, UpdateAccount::getName),
          DiffField.of("section", Account::getSection, UpdateAccount::getSection)
      );

      Set<String> diff = new HashSet<>();
      //loop over the things you want to diff-check
      for(DiffField df:diffFieldList) {
        String valAccount = df.accountGetter.apply(account);
        String valUpdateAccount = df.updateAccountGetter.apply(updateAccount);
        if(!valAccount.equals(valUpdateAccount)){ //TODO: NPE?
          diff.add(df.fieldname);
        }
      }
      System.out.println(diff);
    }
  }
```

But as I already mentioned in the comment above, your current code is much shorter and more precise. This only starts to pay off when you have several more fields to check, and you still have to list these fields manually in the `List<DiffField>`. It only saves you the many `if`s.